# Como guardar String[] no MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Olá, eu gostaria de salvar uma `String[]` no MySQL, mas não sei o tipo de `datatype` que salva `String[]`, e nem qual método uso para guardar essa informação.

Comment: Você já estudou sobre JDBC, Hibernate ou alguma forma de integrar o código java com o SGBD?

Comment: @Douglas não, ainda não.

Comment: Recomendo então estudar a respeito. Não tem segredo, mas será melhor pra você :)

Comment: Tem algum conteúdo especifico sobre String[] ??

Comment: Como lhe expliquei, é melhor dar uma lida, pois é uma área muito complexa. :)

Comment: @LucasCarezia Eu particularmente salvaria no banco como sendo uma tabela unica, separada cada indice do array por uma virgula no banco. Exemplo: valor1,valor2,valor3.

Comment: Como array é um atributos com dados multi-valorados, o ideal seria você ter um tabela separada para cada informação do array, onde cada tupla teria a chave estrangeira referenciando quem detém o array.

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que você esteja usando a linguagem Java e JDBC para acesso ao banco, mas não foi muito bem especificado.

Mas você pode fazer algo assim:
String[] array = { "java", "JDBC", "Hibernate" };

String vetorString = Arrays.toString(array);
//a string vai ser: [java, JDBC, Hibernate]

Então salva o vetorString no banco como tipo VARCHAR. É uma opção, mas aconselho a estudar sobre ORM e persistencia de objeto.

Comment: E na hora de pegar do Banco de Dados, como transformar em String[] novamente ??